# App crash when NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore randomly

Tags: ios

At application(_: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)-> Bool. I write code init CoreData, create a sqlite file in app group directory.
Everything works fine at develop and test. when I publish App to AppStore, I get some report about crash.

NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/979F9001-AFCB-4BA2-BDDF-0CF816BA38C3/Documents/db.sqlite, reason=Component of path /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/979F9001-AFCB-4BA2-BDDF-0CF816BA38C3/Documents/db.sqlite is not a directory

It's happened randomly, low probability.

I don't know why ... maybe App Group not prepared when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? how to fix it ...

```swift
func prepareDatabase()throws { 
    let dirURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.my.app")!
    let document = dirURL.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: document.path) == false {
        try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: document, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    let storeURL = dirURL.appendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")
    guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "db", withExtension: "momd") else {
        throw AppError.GuardError(with: "can't find db.momd")
    }
    guard let model : NSManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
        throw AppError.GuardError("NSManagedObjectModel can not create by file at \(modelURL)")
    }
    let coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
    let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : true]
    try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: options) // I think the problem is here
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
}
```

Comment: But how can it be.. this App Group Directory is used by My App Only. And there is no other place create this File(or directory).

Comment: I am developing another APP, want use same App Group with this one. And still in progress, not published yet :(